# libGDX Pokemon Style Movement (Turning before Moving)

Tags: java, libgdx

I am working on a Pokemon remake in libGDX and I am having some trouble with movement, I can make the player move in a grid just like in the games and I am happy with what I have. However, I want to make it so that if the player is facing left and the player taps right, the player will turn to the right without moving to the right, currently the player moves in the direction you press no matter what.

Code:

```
    // Detects if the player is sprinting
    if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.A)) {
        speed = 2;
    } else {
        speed = 1;
    }

    // Moves the player 
    if (isMoving) {
        // Sets the player animation
        if (speed == 1)
            player.setStance(Stance.WALKING);
        else if (speed == 2)
            player.setStance(Stance.RUNNING);

        if (player.getSprite().getX() < targetX) {
            player.getSprite().translateX(speed);
        }

        if (player.getSprite().getX() > targetX) {
            player.getSprite().translateX(-speed);
        }

        if (player.getSprite().getY() < targetY) {
            player.getSprite().translateY(speed);
        }

        if (player.getSprite().getY() > targetY) {
            player.getSprite().translateY(-speed);
        }

        if (Math.abs(player.getSprite().getX() - targetX) <= 1 && Math.abs(player.getSprite().getY() - targetY) <= 1) {
            player.getSprite().setPosition(targetX, targetY);
            isMoving = false;
        }
    } else {
        player.setStance(Stance.IDLE);
    }

    if (!lockMovement) {
        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP)) {
            if (!isMoving) {
                player.setDirection(Direction.UP);
                if (cellAvailable(player.getSprite().getX() + 8, player.getSprite().getY() + 24)) {
                    isMoving = true;
                    targetY = player.getSprite().getY() + 16;
                    targetX = player.getSprite().getX();
                }
            }
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.DOWN)) {
            if (!isMoving) {
                player.setDirection(Direction.DOWN);
                if (cellAvailable(player.getSprite().getX() + 8, player.getSprite().getY() - 8)) {
                    isMoving = true;
                    targetY = player.getSprite().getY() - 16;
                    targetX = player.getSprite().getX();
                }
            }
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.LEFT)) {
            if (!isMoving) {
                player.setDirection(Direction.LEFT);
                if (cellAvailable(player.getSprite().getX() - 8, player.getSprite().getY() + 8)) {
                    isMoving = true;
                    targetX = player.getSprite().getX() - 16;
                    targetY = player.getSprite().getY();
                }
            }
        }

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.RIGHT)) {
            if (!isMoving) {
                player.setDirection(Direction.RIGHT);
                if (cellAvailable(player.getSprite().getX() + 24, player.getSprite().getY() + 8)) {
                    isMoving = true;
                    targetX = player.getSprite().getX() + 16;
                    targetY = player.getSprite().getY();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Note:
Stances include IDLE, WALKING, and RUNNING

Directions include UP, DOWN, LEFT, RIGHT

Essentially I want the player to stay IDLE and face the direction the user presses THEN move if the key is still being held

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you can do is check if the player is facing the direction you pressed or not. If he is then move the player, else just change his direction to face where you pressed.

```
if(Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.UP) {
    if(player.getDirection() == Direction.UP) {
        if(timeout < 0) {
            // move player
        }
    } else {
        player.setDirection(Direction.UP);
        //Set some timeout in seconds
        timeout = 0.5;
    }
}

//Considering that this method is being called in your update method then reduce the timeout.
timeout -= Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
```

Do the same thing for the other arrow keys as well.

Comment: I've tried this, and the player still moves because the direction gets set, and the key is still held the next frame so the player moves

Comment: @TylerFriesen the issue here is that your update method is being called multiple times in a second. When you press any key, it records the input, sets the players direction and immediately your update is called again while your key is still down so it moves your player. You should try what Squiddie said. I updated my code to add his suggestion.

Comment: @Squiddie please verify if I incorporated your suggestion correctly. I haven't worked with LibGDX in a long time, so I'm not sure if I have done this correctly.

Comment: The timeout works perfectly, thanks, just had to change the delay to be smaller so you don't have to wait so long before changing direction